# Python Multiuser Text Message Server

Tags: python

I have been working on building a program with a tutor for the past four days and I feel like he's dragging the sessions at $74/hr. Can someone help me finish this? What I have to do is listed below along with the code I have done. Right now my code can connect multiusers.

Objective :You are required to send text messages from one client to another client via the server. The text messages must be encrypted during the transmission and decrypted when they reach another client. The related information of encryption, decryption, and the transmission via the server must be printed out. The encryption and decryption are required to use RSA. The integrity of each message should be check to ensure there is no lost/tampered information during the transmission

Code:

```
import socket
import os
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP



name = input("What is this client's name: ")
name = name.strip()


# Generate RSA key pair
key = RSA.generate(2048)
private_key = key.export_key()
public_key = key.publickey().export_key()

# Create a socket object
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

PORT = 2004
# Connect to the server
client_socket.connect(('localhost', PORT))
print('Connected to server')
# Get initial response from server (HELO)
data = client_socket.recv(1024)
print(data)


while True:
    print("1) Check for messages.")
    print("2) Send a message.")
    choice = input()
    if choice == "1":
        # ask server for messages
        pass
    elif choice == "2":
        # routine to write and send message
        pass
    else:
        continue
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)


client_socket.close()

I don't know how to encrypt before sending the messages and decrypt through the server.
```